# What is the use case of Parity's passive sync mode?

Tags: parity, synchronization, configuration

The Parity Ethereum client has four sync modes, two of which are `active` and `passive`. `Active` makes perfect sense to me, Parity continuously syncs the chain. However `passive` says "parity syncs initially, then sleeps and wakes regularly to resync".

Why would anyone choose `passive` instead of `active`? In other words, what is the use case for `passive` sync?

Comment: I'd guess the case you are over a metered connection or a low bandwith link.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you for the reply. Wouldn't they both use the same amount of overall data though, just `passive` would do it in small bursts? Or does the `active` mode propogate more transactions which uses more bandwidth?

Comment: I think you are right from their [configuration wiki page](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity). In active mode it communicates all the time with other nodes; and in passive mode it wakes up regularly but most of the time it is sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parity passive basically lets you to fine tune the way how *active* your node is. This can be due to multiple reasons:

- energy consumption of IoT devices (less CPU cycles, etc.)
- bandwidth consumption on mobile connections (less tx-forwarding, etc.)

To understand the power of that configuration options, also have a look at `--mode-timeout` and `--mode-alarm`

```
--mode=[MODE]
    Set the operating mode. MODE can be one of:
        last - Uses the last-used mode, active if none.
        active - Parity continuously syncs the chain.
        passive - Parity syncs initially, then sleeps and wakes regularly to resync.
        dark - Parity syncs only when the RPC is active.
        offline - Parity doesn't sync. (default: last)
--mode-timeout=[SECS]
    Specify the number of seconds before inactivity timeout occurs when mode is dark or passive (default: 300)
--mode-alarm=[SECS]
    Specify the number of seconds before auto sleep reawake timeout occurs when mode is passive (default: 3600)
```

Which gives you full control beyond the default configuration options.